# Java JRE: How to add localized resources to stantard JRE resources

Tags: localization, properties, java

I need the JRE to use translated versions of a JRE resource that is available only in English.

As per the ResourceBundle.java doc, it's easy: add localized resources with the right locale suffix. For example, the standard

- XMLSchemaMessages.properties

would become a translated version:

- XMLSchemaMessages_FR.properties

And so on.

EDIT: this particular file lives in :
    com\sun\org\apache\xerces\internal\impl\msg\XMLSchemaMessages.properties

My question is: how do I make those extra resources visible to the JRE ?

Thanks in advance, for any help.
-- cheers

Comment: What exactly is it you need to have localized?

Comment: Precisely com\sun\org\apache\xerces\internal\impl\msg\XMLSchemaMessages.properties

Comment: Please note that `_FR` is an invalid locale identifier. It should have been `_fr` (for French language in general, irrespective of the country) or `_fr_FR` (for French language in country France). As to the concrete question: well, perhaps just drop it in the runtime classpath? Localizing JAXP messages has never bothered me, so I wouldn't know the exact answer from top of head but fact is, `ResourceBundle` reads them from the runtime classpath. You just have to make sure that it is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that Xerces uses ResourceBundle to get the messages, you should put a new file in

```
com\sun\org\apache\xerces\internal\impl\msg\XMLSchemaMessages<locale>.properties
```

where locale is a correct identifier for the locale you need.

Then pinpoint the exact location where the XMLSchemaMessages resource bundle is loaded, and set a breakpoint so you single step through the ResourceBundle loading procedure in the JRE (a JDK is recommended here, so you have source for the runtime) and you can see what is being searched for.

Note:  You are dealing with a vendor specific XML Parser here meaning this will be Oracle specific and may even only work on some Java versions.  Considered bringing in your own validating XML Parser and localize it instead?

Comment: Well, finally got it working, rather straightforward:  Just drop the localized resources with their proper '_fr' suffix, in the jre/lib/ext directory. The catch was that they had be in '.jar' format (not '.class'). This was the only way I found where the resource was visible to multiple Tomcat webapps.

Answer (score 2):

The above answers took me a little while to work out.

Just to make it easier for others, here's my summary of how to get Locale specific error messages to appear if you try parsing an XML document using XML schema with Java's internal Xerces parser:

Find an appropriate properties file in the format

```
XMLSchemaMessages_<lower_case_language_code>.properties
```

For Italian I found XMLSchemaMessages_it.properties on the following site (which might be an old version, but it worked for me)

```
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.xml.parsers/jaxp-ri/1.4.5/com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/impl/msg/XMLSchemaMessages_it.properties
```

I then created a directory structure in my temp directory to hold the new file

```
com\sun\org\apache\xerces\internal\impl\msg
```

Since jar files and zip files share the same format (and I'm lazy and today I was using Windows), I then zipped the above com directory, creating a file called com.zip. I then changed the name of the file

```
rename com.zip to XMLSchemaMessages_Locale.jar
```

and then moved the new jar file to

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\jre\lib\ext
```

Of course the above path depends on your platform and specific version of Java (I was using Windows 7).

Instead of zipping, if you have JDK you could easily build the jar file using the command-line *jar* command, from Unix, Linux or Windows.